# Integral $ \int \frac{1}{x^{1+a} (1-x)^{1-a}} dx~,~a \gt 0$

Tags: calculus, integration

The following integral is part of a large problem I'm trying to solve and I'm stuck. I'd appreciate some guidance.

I would like to know how to compute integrals of the form

> $$ \int \frac{1}{x^{1+a} (1-x)^{1-a}} dx~,~a \gt 0$$

[This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F%28x%5E%7B1%2Ba%7D*%281-x%29%5E%7B1-a%7D%29) is the answer WolframAlpha gives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the integral as:
$$ \int \frac{1}{x(1-x)}\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)^a\,dx = \int \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)^{a-1}\,dx$$
and notice that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x-1}{x} = \frac{1}{x^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int \frac{1}{x^{1+a}(1-x)^{1-a}}dx = \int \frac{1}{x(1-x)}\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)^adx
$$
let $u = \frac{1-x}{x} = \frac{1}{x}-1\implies du = -\frac{1}{x^2}dx$
$$
-\int \frac{x}{x-1}u^adu = -\int \frac{1}{u}u^a du = -\int u^{a-1}du
$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute 
$$
y = \frac{1-x}{x} \\
x = \frac{1}{y+1} \\
dx = -(y+1)^{-2}dy
$$
The integral becomes 
$$
-\int y^{a-1} dy = -\frac{1}{a}y^a = -\frac{1}{a} (1-x)^a x^{-a}
$$