# How to use substitution to integrate a function.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

It has been taught to me that integration using substitution method is somewhat reverse of differentiation through chain rule. While chain rule is very algorithmic and doesn't require intuition, substitution method requires intuition and trial & error.
I was doing the following integral:
$$
\int \frac{1}{(x+2)^{5/4}(x-1)^{3/4}}dx
$$
and performed the following substition:
$$
y=(x-1)^{1/4} 
$$
which reduced the integral to:
$$
4\int \frac{1}{(y^4+3)^{5/4}}dy
$$
Sometimes the required substitution is clearly visible and sometimes its not. I really do not know what substitution to do further, is there any method or algorithm which can at least hint me which substitutions to make in such situations?

Comment: *the substitution method requires intuition and trial and error*—You have answered your own question

Comment: There are different patterns which reaper in popular/common integrals and one might recognize after having solved multiple integrals. At first it is recommended to try out a lot. Also tools, like integral calculators, that give the solution path are quite useful in that case.

Comment: Have you looked at the function $f(x)=\sqrt[4]{\frac{x-1}{x+2}}$?

Comment: You can just rewrite $$\dfrac1{(x+2)^\frac54(x-1)^\frac34}=\dfrac1{(x+2)^{\frac54+\frac34}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+2}\right)^\frac34}=\frac1{(x+2)^2\left(\frac{x-1}{x+2}\right)^\frac34}$$

Comment: @Invisible thanks, that certainly does solve the problem. However, I was looking for a general method which can be applied to get the required substitutions.

Comment: This is _somewhat_ similar to [$\int\frac1{x^{1+a}(1+x)^{1-a}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1125117/721644). Sometimes it might help to look at the exponents. Maybe that will remind of something else. For example, $\frac54=1+\frac14$ and $\frac34=1-\frac14,$ so I tried something from there.

Comment: Another solution: Rewrite the denominator as $\sqrt{x+2}\,(x+2)^{3/4}(x-1)^{3/4}$, then substitute $y=\sqrt{x+2}$ followed by $z=y^{-1/2}$. The next step should be obvious.$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+2}\,(x+2)^{3/4}(x-1)^{3/4}}=\int\frac{2\,dy}{y^{3/2}\left(y^2-3\right)^{3/4}}=\int\frac{-4z^3\,dz}{\left(1-3z^4\right)^{3/4}}$$

Comment: @AniketHarit If the obvious algebraic substitutions start failing, trigonometric substitutions are your next best friend.

Answer (score 2):

(did not fit in the comments)

Here's your generalized result specific to such kinds of integrals;
$$I=\int \frac{1}{(x+a)^{\frac{m}{n}}(x+b)^{\frac{p}{n}}}\,dx$$

Where $\frac{m}{n}+\frac{p}{n}=2$

Factor out $(x+a)$,

$$I=\int \frac{1}{(x+a)^{2}\left(\frac{x+b}{x+a}\right)^{\frac{p}{n}}}\,dx$$

> Just to visualize;
>
> $$I=\int
>  \frac{1}{(x+a)^{\frac{m}{n}+\frac{p}{n}}\left(\frac{x+b}{x+a}\right)^{\frac{p}{n}}}\,dx$$

Put $\left(\frac{x+b}{x+a}\right)=t$ and $\frac{1}{a-b}dt=\frac{1}{(x+a)^2}dx$

$$I(a;b;m;p;n) = \frac{1}{a-b} \int \frac{1}{t^{\frac{p}{n}}} dt$$

$$I(a;b;m;p;n) = \frac{1}{a-b} \left[\frac{t^{\frac{-p}{n}+1}}{\frac{-p}{n}+1}\right]+c$$

$$I(a;b;m;p;n) = \frac{1}{a-b} \left[\frac{t^{\frac{-p}{n}+1}}{\frac{-p}{n}+1}\right]+c$$

> $$I(a;b;m;p;n)=\frac{n}{(n-p)(a-b)} \left[\frac{x+b}{x+a}\right]^{\frac{n-p}{n}}+c$$

The original question will then be; $I(2;-1;5;3;4)=\frac{4}{3} \left[\frac{x-1}{x+2}\right]^{\frac{1}{4}}+c$